# HTML5 Canvas choppy graphics when animating

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

When animating one layer in canvas the graphics become choppy if there are other layers present, see fiddle (click RUN to see animation): http://jsfiddle.net/Q97Wn/

If i change this line:

```
opts.percentageIndicator.clearRect(0, 0, opts.percentageIndicator.width, opts.percentageIndicator.height);
```

To:

```
opts.percentageIndicator.clearRect(0, 0, opts.canvas.width, opts.canvas.height);
```

Then everything goes smoothly, except that this will remove the other layer completely.

I could solve this issue by having both in one canvas each, but i was hoping for structure-purposes that i could avoid that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, canvas.getContext() not generating new context, it returning already existing instance, so the lines:

```
opts.centerCircle = opts.canvas.getContext('2d');
// ...
opts.percentageIndicator = opts.canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Would mean the same thing.

So I advice you to do like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Volter9/Q97Wn/2/

What I did I just changed both contexts to one property and after rendering base added:

```
opts.ctx.strokeStyle = opts.indicatorColor;
```

Good luck!